# How to use DomDocument to get google related search result

Tags: php, domdocument

I want to get all related keyword from google search.
[Google Related Searches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIGEk.png)

but when i try to get the container tag (g-section-with-header) with getElementsByTagName it returns null.
what is the problem?
here is my code:

```
/* Createa a new DomDocument object */
$dom = new DomDocument;
/* Load the HTML */
$dom->loadHTML( file_get_contents( 'https://www.google.com/search?q=hello' ) );
$foo = $dom->getElementsByTagName( 'g-section-with-header' );
print_r( $foo );
```

Comment: It's probably not available on page load, and dynamically injected shortly afterwards.

Comment: @ObsidianAge So what Should I do?

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns a `DOMNodeList` object. Have you tried echoing out the `nodeValue` like in the example at : http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php

Comment: @Anthony I understand this.this script will return this:DOMNodeList Object ( [length] => 0 ) so my problem here is not about echoing it

Comment: It's because that URL redirects to another URL via HTML (which `file_get_contents` wouldn't deal with). If you look at the actual payload of `file_get_contents( 'https://www.google.com/search?q=hello' )`, you'll see that it doesn't have any `g-section-with-header` tags. And that it also has `<meta content="0;url=/search?q=hello&amp;ie=UTF-8&amp;gbv=1&amp;sei=IjyPWo3aBsKKjwPp_pLwBw" http-equiv="refresh">`, which triggers the browser to redirect to that URL.

Comment: No wait. Scratch that. I think the issue is with google returning results dependant on the User Agent string. It would probably be easier to use curl to fetch the content (with a UA string google likes), but keep in mind that this could technically be seen as a violation of their Terms of Service, since "robot" clients are expected to honor a site's robots.txt.